# Preposition for "drive to"

Tags: verbes, prépositions

What is the correct preposition to use with the verb *conduire* (to drive)? I suspect it is *à* but I cannot find any examples. I wanted to express this thought:

> I can drive to Montreal in 7 or 8 hours.
>
> *Je pourrais conduire à Montréal en 7 ou 8 heures.*

Are there any places you could *drive to* that would require a different preposition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Conduire* is a transitive verb, see : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conduire .

The sentence

> Je pourrais conduire à Montréal.

means

> I can drive *inside* Montréal.

The correct sentence is:

> Je pourrais conduire jusqu'à Montréal en 7 ou 8 heures.

or,

> Je pourrais conduire cette voiture *[cette personne]* à Montréal en 7 ou 8 heures.

Comment: How is “conduire is a transitive verb” relevant here? I think it's just misleading, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [M42 answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1926/79), *conduire vers* is also commonly used, but only to express direction. For example, it's possible to use *vers* followed with a city name; that would not mean that this city is your destination, just that it is in your general direction.